# how to get the #perspective div's style transform perspective-origin property

Tags: javascript, css, transform

this is css i am trying to get the perspective-origin

```
 #perspective {
    width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
  margin: 75px 0 0 75px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 transform:perspective-origin(center center);
 }
```

this js i try to get the perspective-origin and i want to get the value
but no work ye

```
function getCssProperty(ele, property) {
var id = document.getElementById(ele);

return
window.getComputedStyle(id, null).getPropertyValue(property);

}//this is first  class perspective and property transform
 console.log(getCssProperty('perspective', 'transform'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.  I will investigate transform:perspective-origin(center center); vs perspective-origin: center center;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head title="StackO">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #perspective {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 75px 0 0 75px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            /*transform: perspective-origin(center center);  this is not valid for the transform property;*/
            perspective-origin: center center;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <input type="button" id="target" value="getEvt" />

    <div id="perspective"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getCssProperty(ele, property) {
            var id = document.getElementById(ele);
            var prop =
            window.getComputedStyle(id, null).getPropertyValue(property);
            return prop;
        }

        $("#target").click(function () {
            var prop = getCssProperty('perspective', 'perspective-origin');
            $("#output").html(prop);
        });
        //console.log(getCssProperty('div2', 'role'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: transform-origin: center center; is valid and shows the same coordinates for center as perspective-origin.  Still searching for the validity of transform: perspective-origin(center center) I do not think this is valid CSS.  You could have a transform: rotateX(30deg); and have this line in my code to return a value (for example): var prop = getCssProperty('perspective', 'transform');